# How to position material menu in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a button at the top right corner in my top navbar. That button simply opens up a mat menu. I want to open that mat menu at a specific position, say at the middle of the screen, how do I go about it?

I have tried this snippet of code below in the `menuOpened()` and button's `onClick()` method, nothing seems to be working and the top, height, width, etc are being overwritten when I open the mat menu.

```
menuOpened() {
        console.log('Menu is open');
        var x: HTMLElement = document.querySelector("div.cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box");
        console.log(x);
        x.style.left= "50%";
        x.style.top= "50%";
        console.log(x.style.top);
        console.log(x);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api), MatMenu has following input:

```
@Input('class')
panelClass: string
```

You can try something like

```html
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [class]="'your-class'">
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Please note, that with default `ViewEncapsulation` setting `.your-class` in your component's CSS/SCSS file will not work. You need to either set component's encapsulation to `ViewEncapsulation.None` (I wouldn't recommend that approach as it makes your component styles affect other elements), use `::ng-deep` ([ref](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)) or add the styles to `styles.scss`.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Angular Material's documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#customizing-menu-position):

> The position can be changed using the xPosition (before | after) and yPosition (above | below)

So position can only be changed to an immediate area around the element that creates it.

You may be interested in [dialogs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview). They allow full control over the position in which they are created.